# Why the new line is not being inserted between two values?

Tags: php

My code is as follows:

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
      echo $i."<br>";
    }
```

and the output I got is:

```
0<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>11<br>12<br>13<br>14<br>15<br>16<br>17<br>18<br>19<br>20<br>21<br>22<br>23<br>24<br>25<br>26<br>27<br>28<br>29<br>30<br>31<br>32<br>33<br>34<br>35<br>36<br>37<br>38<br>39<br>40<br>41<br>42<br>43<br>44<br>45<br>46<br>47<br>48<br>49<br>50<br>51<br>52<br>53<br>54<br>55<br>56<br>57<br>58<br>59<br>60<br>61<br>62<br>63<br>64<br>65<br>66<br>67<br>68<br>69<br>70<br>71<br>72<br>73<br>74<br>75<br>76<br>77<br>78<br>79<br>80<br>81<br>82<br>83<br>84<br>85<br>86<br>87<br>88<br>89<br>90<br>91<br>92<br>93<br>94<br>95<br>96<br>97<br>98<br>99<br>100<br><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why this thing is happening:

Comment: Did you try `<br />` or `\n`?

Comment: Why is what happening?

Comment: if you change `<br>` to `<br/>`

Comment: For the record, `<br />` will ***not*** make any difference.

Comment: If you are looking in the source that is what you get. The actual HTML should be newlines.

Comment: You see HTML code because your response header `Content-Type:` is probablly `text/plain` and not `text/html`.

Comment: For all we know this result is not even being interpreted by a browser, but on the command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because that is what you have programmed. Echo does not auto-append a newline, nor does using `<BR>`.

Change your code to include a newline:

```
for($i=0;$i<=100;$i++){
    echo $i."<br>\n";
}
```